# Angular2 loading/unloading Component from <button>

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular-routing, angular-components

I am trying to do the following:

1. Load a component called 'Make.component'
2. in Make.component.html I would like to have something like this:
   `<button *ngIf="for make in makes" (click)="loadModelsComponent({{ make.id }})"> {{make.name}} </button>`
3. While Models.component is loading, 'unload' (or delete) Make.component.

Basically, what I'm trying to describe here is as follows:
I have a button for every 'Make' which has a unique id (in make.id), When this button is clicked, I would like it to load component 2, Models.component (- note that there is a relation between Makes and Models via Make.id and therefore) I need to pass 'make.id' to Models.component.

I believe I could do this via routing, just not sure how to execute this properly. Code snippets, concepts, and advice are greatly appreciated.

Relevant: I am planning on using a service (accessing Edmunds' API) to get this data, so I need to pass the make.id to models(.component)._myApiService.getModels(make.id)  [pseudocode]

Comment: So when you click a button (which has a given id), you want to load a new component (as in, navigate to a new view) and pass along some data? If so I might have an answer for you, I'll post it. If I'm off base I'll remove it.

Comment: @Tim, this is exactly what I'm trying to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you refer to routing, I'll assume you mean that when you click a button, you want to route to an as-usual configured route, and pass some data along to that new component.

I do it this way: assuming you have a route configured (like any other route), in your button click handler, you could do this (assuming you injected Router):

```
this.router.navigate ( [ '/theRoute', { message: 'somedata' } ] );
```

You consume on the receiving component end this way (assuming you inject ActivatedRoute):

```
this.route.snapshot.params [ 'message' ];
```

I do this here and there, makes it pretty easy. Avoids having to use the ":token" format and all of that in your config, you just config the route simply:

```
{ path: 'myfabroute', component: MyFabComponent }
```

Again, theres other ways to do it. This is what I'm inclined to these days.

Comment: because I am new to this, I would appreciate if you'd be a little more explicit with that you're doing here. Where do these code snippets go?

I plan on using the ":token" format because each model view is unique to the make.id if that makes sense

Comment: I don't use the token format because you don't need it. The token format just gives you a way to pass some dynamic info into the receiving component/view, but that's a little clunky to me. This does the same exact thing, but allows you pass anything; strings, numbers, objects, maps, sets, whatever you need, and everything stays simple and clean.

Comment: Snippet 1 would go in your button click handler. You'd grab whatever id that button holds, send it along in the second argument as { propname : 'my_value' }. The second snippet, just put it in ngOnInit of the component you routed to (the receiving one). Now you have the data you sent into the new component and can do as you need. Note that "propname" and "my_value" can be whatever you like, it could be { incoming_data : some_object_or_string_or_anything }, then you'd catch it in the receiving component by using this.router.snapshot.params [ 'incoming_data' ]

Comment: so I can use my Make to route to /models while passing a 'message' of 'make.id'  with your code? Okay, I understand, Now, how do I capture make.id from my template to my component's function 'getModels()' ?

Comment: Yes the basic idea is, "I am in one component, and need to route to another component, passing it whatever information I want that component to receive". Using tokens, there are restrictions to the kind of data you send unless you start to get fancier; this way, you can send any data very flexibly and it's easy to see what's going on without digging around.

Comment: finally, this router will "destroy" (ngOnDestroy function is initialized) for Makes.component?

Comment: Why do you need to destroy it? Whatever you run in the destroy lifecycle handler will do what you like, but one thing about Angular 2 is it seems pretty good at cleaning itself up. Routing away one from one component should do the trick. If you need to explicitly mop something up though, like a subscription or something when a component unloads though, sure onDestroy will run as usual.

Comment: Make sure you read my answer carefully when implementing; don't forget to do your injections. The start component (the one with the button click handler) needs to have Router injected, and the end component (the receiving one) needs to have ActivatedRoute injected. So you have to import them, put them in the constructor, the usual basic Angular 2 injection thing.